# DataSet Not Using Connection String in app.config

Tags: asp.net, dataset, connection-string

I'm using a dataset in a data access layer of a web application on top of a SQL Server database. As I am about to deploy the app to a web server, I changed the database connection string in the web.config of web app and app.config of dataset class library to point to production server. I have changed connection strings in this manner many times in the past, but this time the dataset seems to continue to point to the development database when I debug, not the one I have configured in the web.config. I have tested the individual table adapters by running queries, and they ARE returning data from the correct database as specified in the app.config file. It is only when I debug that I get data from the wrong database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Visual Studio solved the problem. It indicated that the change to the app.config file had not propagated to the settings file (although I had changed it manually myself).